# Transliteration

Tags: perl

I got got such line:

```
print "a b c" =~ tr/a-z/c-za-b/r . "\n";
```

Which basically translates `a b c` to `c d e`,but I don't completely understand is how this works.

So, lets have a look at this part:

```
tr/a-z/c-za-b/r
```

`tr` is used in perl for transliterating, which is clear and ok for me.

in the part `/a-z/` part we select all lowercase letters from a to z, the second part `/c-za-b/` is mystery to me, I tried to experiment but can't figure out how this works. Can someone explain how this being converted or link me to some good explanation or manual ?

Thanks

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators Do a ctrl-f for `tr/SEARCHLIST` and you'll find the relevant section

Comment: There's a *"from"* list of letters on the left and a *"to"* list of letters on the right. Each single letter that occurs in the left list is transliterated into the corresponding one in the right list.

Comment: @MarkSetchell make that an answer not a comment

Answer (score 8):

`a-z` is expanded to the 26 character string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`.

`c-za-b` is expanded to the 26 character string `cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab`.

Given the two strings

```
1. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
2. cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
```

`$string =~ tr/a-z/c-za-b/` converts each character it can find in the first row into the corresponding character in the second row.

Similar notation is used to implement the reversible [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) encoding:

```
($encoded = $original) =~ tr/a-zA-Z/n-za-mN-ZA-M/;
($encoded2 = $encoded) =~ tr/a-zA-Z/n-za-mN-ZA-M/; # now $encoded2 eq $original
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone in finding it incomprehensible. tr// is rarely used in modern code.

Anyway, in Perl-speak, if you have a line like:

```
$x=~tr/0-9a-f/a-p/;
```

That is roughly:

```
my @in = (0 .. 9, "a" .. "f");
my @out = ("a" .. "p");
for my $i (0 .. $#in) {
    $x =~ s/$in[$i]/$out[$i]/g;
}
```

It's a little more complicated than that because `tr//` doesn't work iteratively, but this should give you a good sense of what's going on.